# Can I change the core icons - Raspbian Jessie

Tags: boot, images, icons

Is it possible to change the raspberry pi icons on boot startup

[image: 1]

Comment: [Please don't post images of text](http://meta.unix.stackexchange.com/questions/4086/psa-please-dont-post-images-of-text).  If this is on a console, you should be able to copy the boot output from the logs, e.g. `/var/log/boot.log`.

Comment: @jayhendren It was not the text i was focusing on, just the raspberry pi icons up top

Answer (score 2):

You can easily remove it,  adding `logo.nologo` at the end of the first (and only line in the file `/boot/cmdline.txt` . About changing it, you need to rebuild the kernel, I'm not sure it's worth it. You can always run a service that displays an image on the boot.

more informations here: https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/3488